# Apache - how to use auth for a specific location in a .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication

I have a "virtual" URL like `www.abc.com/admin` and I want to protect it with a simple htpasswd. The directory doesn't exist physically. The rest of the page should be accessable for everyone.

I know solutions for real existing directories and found solutions with `<FoldersMatch>` or `<DirectoryMatch>` but unfortunately this doesn't work with my webhoster. Only `<FilesMatch>` does.

Is there another way to get it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Satisfy Any` statement to check that either the request *isn't* for `/admin` or if there is a valid user:

```
# sets ENV if request is for /admin
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/admin no_require_auth=true

# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile /var/www/htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "no_require_auth" var is set
Allow from env=no_require_auth
```